# Limit scope to object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to force user to use `Setter()` function. (User enters code in textbox, then i run it in `eval()` )Here is what i come up with for now. Please check if this code will prevent user for tempering with `Test()` function.

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
var obj = function(){
   var bar = null;
   this.Setter = function(){
      bar = 1
   };
   this.Getter = function(){
      return bar;
   }
}

function context(){
}

function Test(){
   var o = new obj();
   var ctx = new context();

   var ret = function(str,Setter){
      eval(str);
   }.call(ctx,document.getElementById("Text1").value,o.Setter);

   var bar = o.Getter();

   if(bar == null) { alert("Failed!"); return; }

   alert("Congratulations!");
   return;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

Code:<br>
<textarea id="Text1" cols="100" rows="25"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="Test();">Test</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the threat profile that you're trying to protect against here?

Comment: You should try to explain the end result you are trying to achieve. It's not really clear why you are using `eval()` at all.

Comment: _"check if this code will prevent user for tempering with Test()"_ no, it won't as it is globally defined thus a user could easily just overwrite it like so, `window.Test = function(){}`. As Mark says you need to expand on what you are wanting to happen here. _"force user to use Setter()"_ in what way? Do you mean user is supposed to be writing in some executable code in the textbox and you want them to at some point in their code to call Setter?

Comment: @Patric: yes user should at some point call Setter(); if user overloads Test() it shouldn't affect current executing Test() function.

Comment: @ajxs: what is the "threat profile"?

Comment: By threat profile ajxs is meaning what are you wanting to prevent the user from doing, ie you say tampering with `Test()` in what way did you mean tampering with it? Did you mean something like _"does this prevent users from making it so the o.Getter() test never fails"_? If so then no that doesn't prevent that as user could write `o.Getter = ()=>1`

Comment: You are right this cracks it. Do you have any solution how to force user to use Setter();

Comment: It is a silly to think it might be possible to force a user in any direction, if you pass the user code to eval. If you want to force the user, you have to write your own parser and evaluator. As a starting point read this: https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-25.html#%_chap_4

Comment: So you are saying I should run it to static code analisys and evaluate it in some kind of sandbox? Then i should also have some kind of timer, if it doesn't call Setter() in a given time it fails. Btw. this link won't load is it chapter 4?